# Running a shell command in python, on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, worker, dyno

I have an installed free account on Heroku to get started.

A python code that accepts web requests is starting a shell subprocess, does starting this subprocess count and need a dyno?

I am seeing this specific code not do its intended purpose, but when run through the shell on Heroku it does what it is supposed too.

Comment: If you run`heroku run` you start a one-off dyno (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos). What comand are you executing?

Comment: It's a command that invokes gerbv with some switches. The same command I can run in the shell.